# How to cast string datatype column to date in laravel query?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, casting

I have a laravel query that extracts a year and a day in a column called "schedule". However that column is declared as string datatype and not date. So doing `whereYear('schedule', $year)` doesn't work and it says I have to use explicit typecast. I have done search on this but still never figure this out. There are suggestions like using protect $dates and $cast in model but still never figured it out. Is there a way I can do casting in my controller shown below? If not, how should I solve this? Please help. Thanks a lot.

```
$billDetails = Bill::whereYear(CAST('schedule' AS DATE), $year)
                   ->whereDay(CAST('schedule' AS DATE), '<=', 15)
                   ->where('invalid', false)
                   ->orderBy('loan_id','ASC')
                   ->orderBy('schedule', 'ASC')
                   ->get();
```

Error log

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, character varying) does not exist LINE 1: select * from "bills" where extract(year from "schedule") = ... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "bills" where extract(year from "schedule") = 2021 and extract(day from "schedule") <= 15 and "invalid" = 0 order by "loan_id" asc, "schedule" asc)

SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, character varying) does not exist LINE 1: select * from "bills" where extract(year from "schedule") = ... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "bills" where extract(year from "schedule") = 2021 and extract(day from "schedule") <= 15 and "invalid" = 0 order by "loan_id" asc, "schedule" asc)
```

Comment: The column type shouldn't matter if you're storing the date in a proper format. MySQL `YEAR` function will work just fine with VARCHAR columns.

Comment: When you say doesn't work, you mean you get no output?

Comment: whereYear should work? whereYear('schedule', $year)  what exact error does it give?

Comment: I added in my post the error log. Please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: did you try to use Carbon before? it is awesome when dealing with dates this is the link for official documentation https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/